# How to simulate a table join on itself?

Tags: mysql, join

Let's assume this is my current data:

```
product_number  date         value
100             2010-01-01   1
100             2010-02-01   1
100             2010-03-01   1
200             2010-01-01   1
200             2010-03-01   1
```

How can I join the table on "itself", to fill the dates where other products have missing dates (compared to all the results, that change all the time)?

As you can see, product #200 doesn't have a 2010-02-01 date and I need to get a NULL value there.

Expected result:

```
product_number  date         value
100             2010-01-01   1
100             2010-02-01   1
100             2010-03-01   1
200             2010-01-01   1
200             2010-02-01   NULL # add NULL values where it doesn't have a date
200             2010-03-01   1
```

Basically: get a list of all distinct dates, find products where that date doesn't exist and simulate an entry with a NULL or empty value to fill the gap

Comment: This question/Answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/75752/1504882 suggests creating a table filled with dates to join onto. Using that method you could select from the date table, and left join your table on date. This would effectively show all dates with Null where appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to first create a list of every `product_number` and `date` combination. You can do this using a `CROSS JOIN` of your table:

```
select distinct p.product_number, d.date
from yourtable p
cross join yourtable d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8db81/6). This will create a list of data similar to:

```
| PRODUCT_NUMBER |                            DATE |
|----------------|---------------------------------|
|            100 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |
|            200 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |
|            100 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |
```

You will then use the above query and `LEFT JOIN` to your table to return the final result:

```
select 
  pd.product_number,
  pd.date,
  t.value
from
(
  -- list of every product/date
  select distinct p.product_number, d.date
  from yourtable p
  cross join yourtable d
) pd
left join yourtable t
  on pd.date = t.date
  and pd.product_number = t.product_number
order by pd.product_number, pd.date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8db81/7/0).  Giving a final result of:

```
| PRODUCT_NUMBER |                            DATE |  VALUE |
|----------------|---------------------------------|--------|
|            100 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            100 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            100 |    March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            200 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            200 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
|            200 |    March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
```

The `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from your list of products and dates regardless of whether a matching row exists in the other table.

This could also be written as:

```
select 
  p.product_number,
  d.date,
  t.value
from
(
  -- list of every product
  select distinct product_number
  from yourtable 
) p  
cross join
( 
  -- list of every date
  select distinct date
  from yourtable 
) d
  -- then join to the table
left join yourtable t
  on  d.date = t.date
  and p.product_number = t.product_number
order by p.product_number, d.date ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab5d4/4). This may have better performance depending on your table size.

Now if you wanted to return a list of all dates, regardless of whether or not they appear in the table, then I would suggest creating a table of dates.  This table would be used in a similar manner to create a list of all dates/products which you would then join.

The table would be similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
    (`date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO dates
    (`date`)
VALUES
    ('2010-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2010-02-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2010-03-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2010-04-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2010-05-01 00:00:00')
;
```

You'd then use the following query to get the list of dates/products:

```
select distinct p.product_number, d.date
from yourtable p
cross join dates d
```

And finally, you would join that back to your table:

```
select 
  pd.product_number,
  pd.date,
  t.value
from
(
  -- list of every product/date
  select distinct p.product_number, d.date
  from yourtable p
  cross join dates d
) pd
left join yourtable t
  on pd.date = t.date
  and pd.product_number = t.product_number
order by pd.product_number, pd.date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab5d4/2/0). Or an alternative:

```
select 
  p.product_number,
  d.date,
  t.value
from
(
  -- list of every product
  select distinct product_number
  from yourtable 
) p  
cross join
 dates
  d
  -- then join to the table
left join yourtable t
  on  d.date = t.date
  and p.product_number = t.product_number
order by p.product_number, d.date ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab5d4/6). Again this may have better performance based on the table size.  Using this type of solution, you'd return all dates even those not in your table:

```
| PRODUCT_NUMBER |                            DATE |  VALUE |
|----------------|---------------------------------|--------|
|            100 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            100 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            100 |    March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            100 |    April, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
|            100 |      May, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
|            200 |  January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            200 | February, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
|            200 |    March, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |
|            200 |    April, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
|            200 |      May, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |
```

Comment: Lovely answer +1. I think that we here on dba.stackexchange should try and encourage new posters to get into the habit of posting their DDL and DML either in the post, on SQL Fiddle or as a download. Maybe a criterion for accepting first posts? I'll bring this up on meta.

Comment: I can't believe I never heard of CROSS JOIN before, that's why I couldn't make sense on how to join the two results. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @hmm It is also called a Cartesian result and instead of using  CROSS JOIN you could use a comma between the 2 tables to get the list all products/dates.  I prefer to state CROSS JOIN so it is clear what you are doing.

Comment: @bluefeet: You can add these [variations](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab5d4/5). They will probably be more efficient on a big table as the derived tables can use indexes and the cross join will have much less rows to produce. And if there is a `products` (or a `dates` table as you suggested), they are easier to convert.